# Preprocessor macro that references a variable that may or may not be defined

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, c-preprocessor

I have two preprocessor macros that log when methods are called. One macro simply logs a method's name; the other macro I use for UITableViewDelegate methods to log a method's name and the value of the argument `indexPath` (an NSIndex* with two indexes).

```
#define LogMethodName  \
    { NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__) ; }
#define LogMethodNameAndIndexPath  \
    { NSLog(@"%s  {%lu, %lu}", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [indexPath indexAtPosition:0] , [indexPath indexAtPosition:1] ) ; }
```

I'm doubtful it's possible, but I'd like a single macro to do the work of these two: when used inside a method that has an `indexPath` argument, it'd perform code similar to `LogMethodNameAndIndexPath`, and when used inside a method that lacks the `indexPath` argument (and thus `indexPath` is undefined), it'd perform code like `LogMethodName`.

Is this possible? I've looked through dozens of Stack Overflow questions, but I haven't found an answer I could comprehend. I've tried the code seen below, but Xcode doesn't like when I reference `indexPath` in line 4 if it's not previously defined, and there's no way to reassure Xcode that I'll ask it to execute line 4 only when `indexPath` is defined.

```
#define LogMethodNameAndIndexPathWhenPresent {                                                                                                    \
    NSString* stringToLog = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__] ;                                                                 \
    if ( [stringToLog hasSuffix:@"AtIndexPath:]" )                                                                                                \
        stringToLog = [stringToLog stringByAppendingFormat:@"  {%lu, %lu}", [indexPath indexAtPosition:0] , [indexPath indexAtPosition:1] ] ;     \
    NSLog(@"%@", stringToLog) ;                                                                                                                   \
}
```

Comment: Why to create a macro? You can do this via a method.

Comment: What would that method look like? Could it be defined in a single place and available for use in any `.m` implementation file?

Comment: Create that method as a factory method inside a class called `LMALog`. Whenever you want call it `[LMALog logMethod];` And import that class in all of your classes.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to pass the method name and optional NSIndexPath as arguments so that the `LMALog` class knows what to log? In practice, I see that as `[LMALog logMethodWithMethodName:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__]` when called inside methods lacking an NSIndexPath, and `[LMALog logMethodWithMethodName:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ andIndexPath:indexPath]` when called inside methods that have an NSIndexPath I'd like to see logged. Both those options require much more typing and effort than the above two macros.

Comment: Yes if you have many variants, create those many methods... I think you already have got the idea. :)

Comment: You can't access local variables (including those passed as arguments to a method) by variable name, which will prove to be a bit of a difficulty for this scheme.  The only approach I can think of (but haven't tried to implement) is to iterate over the implementation's arguments starting at `_cmd` and try to test the type of each (if they were all objects, this would be easy via `-isKindOfClass:` but otherwise...) but this seems at the least extremely hacky and almost certainly dangerous.

Comment: @NateChandler, can you provide code on how to iterate over the implementation's arguments? I've never worked with C arrays, only NSArrays, and I'm struggling. And yes, let's assume all arguments are objects for now.

Comment: Looks like it should be possible using `instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:`, `getArgumentTypeAtIndex:`, `NSGetSizeAndAlignment` and `&_cmd`.